# Using diff in Linux using php's exec function

Tags: php, linux, diff, compare, exec

I have to compare 2 xml files and generate a patch using php and Linux's diff command. Here's my code:

```
<?php

// script file location: /var/local/out/upload.php
// ...

// $templateName file location: /var/local/out/upload/example_word_template/word/document.xml
// $filename file location: /var/local/out/upload/example_word/word/document.xml

// $templateName value: upload/example_word_template/word/document.xml
// $filename value: upload/example_word/word/document.xml

$command = "diff /var/local/out/$templateName /var/local/out/$filename > /var/local/out/patch.patch";
exec($command);
echo($command);

?>
```

The browser outputs:

diff /var/local/out/upload/example_word_template/word/document.xml /var/local/out/upload/example_word/word/document.xml > /var/local/out/patch.patch

If I copy and paste the output and execute it directly in Linux, it runs just fine. But the script itself won't generate the patch file. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking the output of the executed command, maybe the user you are running apache under doesn't have permission to write in that folder or somethin...:

```
$output=array();$status=0;
exec($command,$output,$status);
var_dump($output);var_dump($status);
```

Comment: The output was "array(0) { } int(1)"

Comment: I think it's operation not permitted :) 

http://www.pegasoft.ca/resources/boblap/99_b.html

Comment: The destination directory does not exist, is not writeable or the 'diff' prog was not found / not executable.

Comment: @symcbean can't be "'diff' prog was not found / not executable." because he said it worked in console...

@wilsonsilva have you tried creating the output file manually before executing the command? something like `file_put_contents('/var/local/out/patch.patch','');chmod('/var/local/out/patch.patch',0777);` ?

Comment: I got this erros: Warning: file_put_contents(/var/local/out/patch.patch) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/local/out/upload.php on line 60

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in /var/local/out/upload.php on line 60

Which makes sense because the file doesn't exist before the command execution.

Comment: not really..it should have created the file :) for testing, try changing the permission on /var/local/out to 0777 from command line and try again :)

Comment: I still get the error, BUT! I did a "chmod -R 777 out" and it worked.

Comment: Try searching more info related to permissions/apache maybe you'll get rid of the error two...good luck!

Answer (score 5):

PHP has a [PECL extension for xdiff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xdiff.php) you might want to try instead.

Example from Manual for [`xdiff_file_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-file-diff.php)

```
$old_version = 'my_script.php';
$new_version = 'my_new_script.php';

xdiff_file_diff($old_version, $new_version, 'my_script.diff', 2);
```

Note that diff is on the syntactical level only, while semantically there is no difference between

```
<element foo="foo" bar="bar"/>
```

and

```
<element 
    foo="foo"
    bar="bar"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to capture the output like so...

```
$command = "diff /var/local/out/$templateName /var/local/out/$filename > /var/local/out/patch.patch";
exec($command, $output);

var_dump($output);
```

You can reassemble the lines like so...

```
echo join("\n", $output);
```

Comment: The output was "array(0) { }", I have no clue what it means. I'm still a Linux newbie.

Comment: @wilsonsilva From your other comment, you said the status returned was `1`. This means there was an error. Do your paths point to files that exist?

Comment: Yes. If I execute the following command directly in linux: "diff /var/local/out/upload/example_word_template/word/document.xml /var/local/out/upload/example_word/word/document.xml > /var/local/out/patch.patch" the patch.patch file is created.

Comment: @wilsonsilva You want to read that file into PHP? Try using `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: I'm unable to read it because the file isn't created if I use the php script.